# JEST: how to test function which is executed before any render occurs in React app

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have very short experience with JEST testing. In my React App I have (main)index file with such the content:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import AppProvider from './components/AppProvider';
import breakWhenInternetExplorer from './js/breakWhenInternetExplorer';

breakWhenInternetExplorer();

ReactDOM.render(
    <AppProvider>
        <App />
    </AppProvider>,

    document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

and I'd like to test breakWhenInternetExplorer function call. While testing real components is well documented, I have no clue how to test this function call which has palce before anything else happens. Any ideas?

Comment: Create a file called `breakWhenInternetExplorer.spec.ts` (or .js if you use javascript). Inside of it you import your function and do the test. Understand what you are testing and use mock or spyOn to check its behavior.

Comment: You need to test this function separately